# Checking Members for Nil

Tags: scala

Let's say I have a `Tree` object with 2 member objects, `right` and `left`.

What's the idiomatic/right way to check if `tree`'s "right" and "left" fields are Nil?

```
def count(tree: Tree, acc: Int) : Int = tree match {

  case tree .right != Nil && tree .left != Nil => countLeftAndRight(...)
  case tree .right != Nil => countOnlyRight(...)
  case tree .left  != Nil => countOnlyLeft(...)
  _              => acc
}
```

Comment: What is `x`? Your match block doesn't seem valid.

Comment: sorry - I updated to be `tree`, not `x`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example isn't valid Scala, but the idiomatic way to match the Tree is with an extractor (look it up). You get this for free if `Tree` is a case class. Assuming it is, you can write

```
tree match {
  case Tree(Nil, Nil) => acc
  case Tree(Nil, x) => ...
  case Tree(x, Nil) => ...
  case Tree(x, y) => ...
}
```

Comment: Does the `x` and `y` in the case statements indicate any non-`Nil` value in the `tree` object?

Comment: They are variables that will be bound to the value returned by the extractor. (It's significant that they begin with a lowercase letter.) That can include the value `Nil`, which is why we match on `Nil` first, so the following cases are non-Nil.

Answer (score 3):

Or, if you'd prefer to work with your non-case-class `Tree` as-is, then you might try this variation of Luigi's solution:

```
(tree.left, tree.right) match {
  case (Nil, Nil) => acc
  case (Nil, x) => ...
  case (x, Nil) => ...
  case (x, y) => ...
```